# Finite Product Property

Tags: category-theory

I have a property of finite products in which I ask you for a suggestion.
Suppose $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of objects in the category $\mathcal{C}$. Let's define the category $\mathcal{C}_{A_i}$ as follows: objects are of the form $\widehat{X}_{f_i}=(X,\{ f_i\}_{i\in I})$, where $X\in \mathcal{C}$ and $\{f_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of morphisms on $Mor_\mathcal{C}(X,A_i)$. The morphisms meet
$\widehat{h}\in Mor_{\mathcal{C}_{A_i}}(\widehat{X}_{f_i},\widehat{Y}_{g_i})$ if and only if $h\in Mor_\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ and $g_i\circ{h}=f_i$ for all $i\in I$.

We will denote by $\widehat{X}=(X,\{f_i\}_{i\in I})$, $\widehat{Y}=(Y,\{g_i\}_ {i\in I})$ to the objects of $\mathcal{C}_{A_i}$

The composition is defined as $\widehat{f}\circ{}\widehat{g}:=\widehat{f\circ{g}}$ and the identity map is $1_{\widehat {X}}:=\widehat{1}_X$.

Remark: Two maps $\widehat{f},\widehat{g}\in Mor(\widehat{X},\widehat{Y})$ into $\mathcal{C}_{A_i }$are such that $\widehat{f}=\widehat{g}$ if and only if $f=g$
in $\mathcal{C}$.

Definition: A terminal object $\widehat{X}$ in $\mathcal{C}_{A_i}$, when it exists is called a product of the family $\{A_i \}_{i\in I}$. $X$ will be denoted by $X=\prod_{{i\in I}}^{}A_i$.

Theorem: If there exist the products $(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i,\{f_i\})\in \mathcal{C}_{A_i}$ with $i=1,2,...,n-1$, $((\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times{A_n},\{ p_1,p_n\})\in \mathcal{C}_{A_{\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i,A_n}}$ and $(\prod_{{ i=1}}^{n}A_i,\{a_i\})\in \mathcal{C}_{A_i}$ with $i=1,2,...,n$ then $(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times{A_n}\approx{\prod_{{i=1}}^{n}A_i}$ .
Proof: From the hypotheses we have that $f_i:\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i\longrightarrow{A_i}$, $i=1,2,... ,n-1$; $p_1:(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times{A_n}\longrightarrow{\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i}$; $p_n:(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times{A_n}\longrightarrow{A_n}$ and $a_i:\prod_{{i=1 }}^{n}A_i\longrightarrow{A_i}$ with $i=1,2,...,n$.

Then $f_i\circ{}p_1:(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times{A_n}\longrightarrow{A_i}$, with $i= 1,2,...,n-1$ then $((\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times{A_n},\{f_i\circ{ p_1},p_n\})\in \mathcal{C}_{A_i}$, with $i=1,2,...,n$ and given that $(\ prod_{{i=1}}^{n}A_i,\{a_i\})\in \mathcal{C}_{A_i}$ with $i=1,2,...,n$ is a product so there is a unique $h\in Mor((\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times{A_n},\prod_{{i=1 }}^{n}A_i)$ and $a_n\circ{h}=p_n, a_i\circ{h}=f_i\circ{p_1}$, with i=1 ,2,...,n-1$.

On the other hand $(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n}A_i,\{a_i\})\in \mathcal{C}_{A_i}$ with $i=1 ,2,...,n-1$

then there exists a unique map $g\in Mor(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n}A_i,\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)$ and $f_i\circ{g}=a_i$ with $i=1,2,...,n$. Now we get that $(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n}A_i,\{g,a_n\})\in \mathcal{C}_{A_{\prod_{{i=1}} {n-1}A_i,A_n}}$ then there exists a unique $\phi\in Mor(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n}A_i,(\prod_{{i= 1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times{A_n})$ and $p_1\circ{\phi=g; p_n\circ{\phi=a_n}}$.

From the previous results we obtain that $a_i\circ{(h\circ{\phi})=a_i}$ with $i=1,2,...,n-1$ and also $a_n\circ{(h\circ{\phi})=a_n}$.

Let us denote $A=\prod_{{i=1}}^{n}A_i$ and $B=(\prod_{{i=1}}^{n-1}A_i)\times {A_n}$.

We have that $h\circ{\phi=1_A}$ since $a_i\circ{(h\circ{\phi})=a_i}$ with $i=1, 2,...,n-1$ and $a_n\circ{(h\circ{\phi})=a_n}$.

What I can't get is that $\phi \circ{h}=1_B$. I look forward to any suggestions.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

Just like $h\circ{\phi} =1_A$ because $a_i\circ{(h\circ{\phi})=a_i}$, $\phi \circ h =1_B$ because their compositions with $p_i$ are equal. This follows immediately from how you've defined $\phi$ and $h$ in essentially the same way as $h\circ{\phi} =1_A$. E.g. $p_1 \circ \phi \circ h = (p_1 \circ \phi) \circ h = g \circ h,$ which is $p_1$ because the compositions of these maps to the product $A_1 \times \ldots \times A_{n-1}$ with the projections $f_i: A_1 \times \ldots \times A_{n-1} \to A_i$ are equal: by the definition of $g$, $f_i \circ g \circ h = (f_i \circ g) \circ h = a_i \circ h$, whereas $f_i \circ p_1 = a_i\circ{h}$ is the definition of $h$.

In general the uniqueness of an object with a universal property, like the product in this case, is always proved like this. The universal property enables one to define a pair of maps, and uniqueness implies that these maps are inverses of each other.